# Main menu does not scroll after opening google maps (AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a menu with several functionalities including Google Maps.
The application always works fine until i open the google maps page, and leave it to return to the menu: 
the menu gets stuck and does not scroll anymore and i don't get any errors.

Any idea what may be causing this?
Thank you.